# PHP redirect page

Tags: exception, controller, kohana-3

i have a kohana website, and i want that, if someone modifies the current url (in the browser when he visits the website), and that specific page doesn't exist, he should be redirected to the current page (where he is now), or on the homepage, but without displaying any error.

any idea about how this can be done?

Comment: Which version of kohana do you use? I asume Ko3.x

Answer (score 1):

The [guide](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/tutorials/error-pages) gives the basic steps you need to take.

You basically replace the existing exception handler by defining a class called `Kohana_Exception`.

In that handler, you would check the error number and if it's a 404, then do a redirect based on the http referer.

```
class Kohana extends Kohana_Core
{
    public static function handler(Exception $e)
    {
        if($e instanceof Kohana_Request_Exception)
        {
            Request::current()->redirect(Request::initial()->referrer());
        }
    }
}
```

This should be placed in for example `application/classes/kohana.php`
Note that this is the basic gist. You should expand on this and check if HTTP_Referer is set and based that the user actually came from your site.

Also note that this can cause confusion as people often don't notice they have been redirected.

Check the guide for other things you should do in the exception handler (for example, pass it on to the default handler.

Comment: this tutorial is quite confusing as i don;t understand where should i place the class  Kohana_Exception - in it the actual error controller? (that continues bellow in the page?)

Comment: This informatioin was meant for Kohana 3.1, I need to change it for Kohana 3.0

Comment: also: i should catch and throw the error on every controller? i want this to be default, some how in the bootstrap

Comment: No, Kohana throws exceptions itself. Not however, that there could be more exceptions that indicate a '404' situation. In Kohana 3.1 this is easier because there are special HTTP exceptions.

Comment: is it safe to modify the line: "throw new Kohana_Request_Exception('Unable to find a route to match the URI: :uri',
   array(':uri' => $uri));"

Comment: It is not recomended to change the system files, although, the biggest problem is when needing to update the system. THe problem is, is that it's not the only point where 404's happen. They also happen when the action cannot be found.

Comment: exactly. i have managed to handle 404, but when the action cannot be found... there are problems :(